# Error: 403, Forbidden error in creating circle in Google plus

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

Here, I want to create circle in google plus using API. I got `https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/circles/insert` link for creating circle.

I did my code with perfect.

```
$headers = array
      (
        'Content-Type: application/json'
      );
      
      $ch = curl_init();
      # Setup request to send json via POST.
      $jsonData = json_encode( array( "displayName"=> "abc" ) );
      //echo "https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/".$socialuserId."/circles?access_token=".$accessToken;exit;
      curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/".$socialuserId."/circles?access_token=".$accessToken);
      curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData );
      curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
      curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
      curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
      # Return response instead of printing.
      curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
      # Send request.
      $result = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
```

Here, `$socialuserId` and `$accessToken` I am getting right.
But I am getting Forbidden Error like below.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
```

What can be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "403 forbidden" can be returned if the service is turned off inside the admin console or if the user which you are trying to create a circle for, has not created a Google Plus profile. Here is a sample of an implementation with the Google PHP Client Library version 2.0.3 but your code should also work.

```
<?php

session_start();

//INCLUDE PHP CLIENT LIBRARY
require_once "google-api-php-client-2.0.3/vendor/autoload.php";

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig("client_credentials.json");
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/createCircle.php');
$client->addScope(array(
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.write",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me")
);

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {

    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

    $service = new Google_Service_PlusDomains($client);

    $circle = new Google_Service_PlusDomains_Circle(array(
      'displayName' => 'VIP Circle',
      'description' => 'Best of the best'
      )
    );

    $userId = 'me';

    $newcircle = $service->circles->insert($userId, $circle);

    echo "Circle created: ".$newcircle->id." - ".$newcircle->selfLink;

} else {

    if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {    

          $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
          header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

    } else {  

      $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
      $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

      $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/createCircle.php';
      header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

    }

}


?>
```

Make sure to review the following references: https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/scopes
https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/
https://support.google.com/a/answer/1631746?hl=en

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is that necessary to start session? And where I have to call this `createCircle.php` file?

Comment: In the above example, you have to start a session because that is where the access token is being saved; but you are not REQUIRED to create a session. You can also save the access token to a file and after authenticating you can get the access token from that file. In regards to the `createCircle.php`, is just an example. You can call it `index.php`, `myfile.php`, `test.php` or whatever you want. Like I said, it is just an example of a file stored in the root directory so it can perfectly match the `$redirect_uri` variable value.

Comment: I have just tested your code and it worked for me. This can only mean that either the user has no Google Plus Profile created yet or that the service is turned Off inside the admin console. Please make sure the service is turned on by following the instructions here [https://support.google.com/a/answer/1631746?hl=en] I hope this solves your problem!